# What does "Government is a corporation in the limit" mean?

Tags: meaning

In one of the videos [Elon Musk defines Government](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Government#:%7E:text=government%20is%20just%20a%20corporation%20in%20the%20limit) as a "corporation in the limit". What does "in the limit" mean in this context?

As retweeted, a more complete quotation is:

"Government is just a corporation in the limit. It's the biggest corporation of all and it's got a monopoly on violence. So, if you don't like corporations, you should really hate governments" -
@elonmusk

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the suggested duplicate covers this particular usage. I'll post, though I've not been able to find supporting evidence for my opinion here.

(1) I believe that 'In the limit, g/Government is a corporation' is an acceptable re-ordering, and fronting the prepositional phrase avoids ambiguity.

(2) 'In the limit' would more usually be 'In the final analysis'.

From [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/corporation.asp):

> - A corporation is legally a separate and distinct entity from its owners. Corporations possess many of the same legal rights and
>   responsibilities as individuals.
> - An important element of a corporation is limited liability, which means that its shareholders are not personally responsible for the
>   company's debts.

So,

'The bottom line is, it's just a job: politicians can walk away from any problems they've allowed / caused.'

[edit] The added context suggests that the sense intended could equally be 'a corporation in the limit' = 'the ultimate corporation', but I find this very forced.

Answer (score 0):

In this recently (December 7, 2021) streamed [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSD_vpfikbE) (13:17 to 13:27), Elon Musk expounds on what he meant with the phrase "corporation in the limit" which is that government is a corporation in its maximal or in its most extreme form.